# Crystal Reports - Trending the calculation of two summed "grouped fields" in a Chart?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

OK, imagine that you have two fields, amongst others, in the database table for scoring (evaluation):

1. Actual Value
2. Possible Value

So, if I scored 70 out of 100, on evaluation #1, a record would go in the database with Actual being 70 and possible being 100.

As an employee, I will be evaluated often.  So, this might be something I want to trend and show in a graph:

[image]

What you see here is a sum of all their "actual" values, trending by month (2013-10 is October 2013 ... 2013-11 is November 2013):

1. employee "test, acct" had 2 evals in Oct, and 2 in Nov.  His actual was 0 for all 4 evals.  Hence, he gets 0 plotted in Oct, and 0 plotted in Nov.
2. employee "test, acct2" had 2 evals in Oct and scored 50 both times (100 total), and 10 evals in Nov and scored 100 every time (1000 total).

We are going to ignore the green dot!

This chart works because it looks something like:

[image]

1. YYYY-MM is a formula that returns the text representation of the database date field (again, the text that you see along the x-axis in the chart).
2. GroupBy is a formula that returns the text of the database field that we are grouping by.  In this case it was by employee name (as noted in the legend).
3. SecondGraphField is a formula that returns the database field we will sum.  In this case, the input parameter was "actual", so we returned the actual db field to get summed by the chart.

Now, summing possible and actual and trending that in a chart is easy.  Where I'm stuck is if I wanted to display Percent in the chart.

For "Sum of @SecondGraphField" we need to involve two db fields!  That are individually summed based on our grouping and then divided.  For example, you can't make a third db field (along with possible and actual) called percent, and then take the average of that.  I basically need this:

@SecondGraphField doing the following:

(Sum({table.Actual}, "ourGrouping") / Sum({table.Possible}, "ourGrouping")) * 100

"ourGrouping" being the "OnChangeOf" you see in the Chart Expert.  But, that's two fields, just as it is in the Group Expert of the report.  And Sum is only allowing one field here (the 2nd parameter).

For the report itself, I have multiple running total fields, but I can't utilize that here.  I was thinking of changing the Chart Expert to not summarize the @SecondGraphField forumula, and this forumula instead references/returns the running total field. But, if I do that, it blows up with 'The Report Application Server failed".  So, apparently you can't use Running Total Fields.

How can I trend the percent in a chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Originally, the report looked something like this (notice the two Group Sections I have):

[image]

Instead of @GroupBy and @YYYY-MM (which is a parsed, text version of the db date field), it was @GroupBy and the db date field.

If I changed the Crystal Reports Group Section to YYYY-MM, instead of just the date field (as noted by the red arrows), it made my life easier (forgive me, I was copying an existing report that had the chart expert using YYYY-MM and the Crystal Report using the date field)

This explains why, when I was modifying the "SecondGraphField" formula for the chart to use, I could never get the "Sum" Report fields from the "grouped" section I wanted, to work correctly.  For example, in Formula Workshop, if I dragged the sum of Possible (db field) to my editor I would get something like this:

Sum ({table.Possible}, {table.Date}, "daily")

And if I tried to use it, at run-time, it would blow up with something like this:

Error in Formula.  There must be a group that matches this field.

Being able to use the Sum Report fields allowed me to sum within the forumla (and divide for percent), so the Chart Expert ends up looking like this (don't need to sum SecondGraphField, we sum within the formula):

[image]

Now, if I could, for the life of me, figure out why Crystal removes every field in my Group Section that I modified from table.Date to @YYYY-MM, that would be helpful.  And on top of that, stopping them from doing that?  That would be great.  Crystal can sure be brutal when you want to make changes.